# Out of the range of DateTime (year must be between 1 and 9999) with Entity Framework Core and PostgreSql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, datetime, entity-framework-core

I have the following values in my PostreSql database table on a table column with the data type of `timestamp(0)`:

```
2023-02-17 19:36:58.000,
2023-02-17 19:46:53.000,
2023-02-17 19:53:45.000
```

And when I try to run a select query from Entity Framework Core, I get the following error message

> Out of the range of DateTime (year must be between 1 and 9999)

This is the code

```
 var sessionStatus = await _unitOfWork.SessionStatusRepository.GetAsync(filter: i => i.SessionId == sessionId);
```

This is the repository method below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbset;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (var property in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(property);
        }
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And the `datetime` properties of the entity class as I defined them are as follows:

```
public class Entityname
{
    ...
    public DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Please how can I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: write some more details, please. copy and paste the code here

Comment: @HamidMohammadi I have added more code now

Comment: This `2023-02-17 19:36:58.000` is not timestamp(0) that would be `02/17/2023 19:36:58`.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert timestamp values from the database to `DateTimeOffset`. it represents wide range value that `DataTime`

use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Your date time value".ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Is this to be used in the select query or while inserting the datetime record?

Comment: because of performance, it is better to do it at write time. but you can do it in select query